# Can I use Google Places API to return residential addresses?

Tags: google-places-api

We have an application where users can report incidents and want to allow searches by keyword. The Google Places API (I've tried nearby search, text search, and autocomplete) only returns businesses, but sometimes the user may be on a residential street. How do I get Places to return residential addresses?

I know the data is in there, because if you search on Google Maps, or use the geocode API, you can get an exact address.

Example (picking a random point in London):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&key=[YOUR_KEY]&radius=50000&location=51.611499,-0.026750&keyword=sinclair

returns

```
Sinclair Pharma, 1st Floor Whitfield Court, 30-32 Whitfield Street, London
Sinclair Pharmaceuticals Ltd, Godalming Business Centre, Woolsack Way, Godalming
Sinclair Hammelton Bromley, 23 High Street, Bromley
Sinclair & Rush Ltd, 20 / 20 Business Estate, Spectrum West, Saint Laurence Avenue, Maidstone
Sinclair Hammelton Petts Wood, 9 Fairway, Orpington
Sinclair Till Flooring Co Ltd, 793 Wandsworth Road, London
etc
```

but

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&key=[YOUR_KEY]&latlng=51.611499,-0.026750

returns

```
148 Sinclair Rd, London E4 8PR, UK
```

Answer (score 2):

Does using autocomplete with `type=geocode` or `type=address` do what you want ([link to docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types))?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&key=[YOUR=KEY]&type=geocode&radius=50000&location=51.611499,-0.026750&input=5%20sinclair
```

Comment: No, I've tried autocomplete. Adding types=address doesn't give me any different results - it only returns roads, e.g. "Sinclair Road, London, United Kingdom".

Comment: Try checking "Addresses" in this demo: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete ─ you should see that only address, and no businesses, are suggested.

Comment: It's still returning roads without house numbers. Compare with OS Places Find API, which returns results of individual house numbers on the street.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding might be what you're looking for

> Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)
> The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse